# Rotate x axis text and append label text d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to append x-axis text label and rotate the x axis labels.
Both works individually but I cant figure out how to use them both together.Can someone please help.[image]

```
 g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
  .selectAll("text")    // either this 
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".1em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)")
   .append("text")// or this
   .attr("x", width)
   .attr("y", -6)
   .style("text-anchor", "end")
   .style("font-weight", "bold")
   .style("fill", "black")
   .text(tooltipTxt);
```

Comment: Can you provide any JSFiddle link where we can work on?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zg65cdq0/

Comment: The JSFiddle link works fine. It appends `x` axis labels and is rotated. (atleast for me)